# MongoDB java List database name and the collections related to it

Tags: java, mongodb

I have 3 databases and in each one I have two collections, so I want to display each database and the collections related to it in a treeview.
Can you please guys help me and suggest some ideas or tutorials?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider the mongo documentation as an excellent starting point, they have some great getting started tutorials https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/getting-started/ and can also get you started with drivers for whatever language is your poison https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/